# Невидимая форма

Tags: delphi

Как сделать так, чтобы вся форма была прозрачной, а были видны только компоненты?

Т.е. тупо картинка `image` посреди экрана, либо `label` (надпись).

Нужно убрать рамки и сделать прозрачную саму форму (без компонентов).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Точно не знаю, но, может, этого можно добиться с помощью `borderStyle None` и `TransperentColor`?

Answer (score 1):

По поводу рамки гуглите в сторону `WM_NCPAINT`.

По поводу создания формы произвольных размеров - `CreateWindowRegion`.

Answer (score 1):

Настроить свойства формы: `Transparent=True`, в `TransparentColor` указать тот цвет, который ни для каких других элементов управления использоваться не будет (желательно какой-нибудь яркий: `clYellow, clFuchsia`) и поставить этот же цвет в свойстве `Color` формы. Все эти свойства, конечно же, можно устанавливать программно, но это необходимо для тех случаев, когда может измениться цвет элементов управления: надписей и др. А рамка у формы убирается свойством `BorderStyle` со значением `bsNone`.

Answer (score 0):

Не помню с какой версии Делфей, но у формы появились свойства AlphaBlend и AlphaBlendValue как раз для этого предназначение. Но есть оговорка, работает в Виндах начиная с Windows 2000. То есть, на НТ4, Ме, 9х прозрачности не будет.

Comment: перечитайте еще раз вопрос:

>> Как сделать так, чтобы вся форма была прозрачной, а были видны только компоненты?

AlphaBlend действует только на форму ? Edit, Memo, Button и т.д остаются на 100% видимыми ?

Comment: Хм.. не помню.. возможно я и не прав

Comment: Тогда надо юзать CreateWindowRegion

Comment: Свойства AlphaBlend и AlphaBlendValue действуют не только на форму, но и на компоненты - например - если AlphaBlend=True и AlphaBlendValue=175, то прозрачность формы и компонентов будет чуть больше, чем 50%.